# How to find the space used by all folders present in D drive?

Tags: python, directory

I want to keep track of the size of all folders present in my d drive so I can create a database for the same in Microsoft access. Does anyone have any idea how to code that preferably in python? I have looked through similar questions here but the code displays the size of a single folder present in the drive but I want it to display the size of all the folders present in the drive.
Would mean a lot if anyone has any idea regarding that. Thanks!

(eg: if my D drive has 4 folders then I want it to display the size of all 4 folders, and next day if I add an additional folder to my drive then when I run the code I want it to display the size of all 5 folders now, this way I can create database for the same.)

```
import os
import math as m

current_wd = os.getcwd()

directory_location = "D:\Demofolder"
New_wd = os.chdir(directory_location)

current_wd = os.getcwd()
#print(current_wd)

#print(os.path.getsize(directory_location))

total_dir_size=0
for file in os.listdir():
 #   print(file)
  x =  os.path.getsize(directory_location + "/" + file)
  x_in_kb = x/1024
  total_dir_size += x_in_kb
 # print(x_in_kb)
 # 
print(str(m.trunc(total_dir_size))+ "kb")
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried which displays the size of a single folder.

Comment: yes sure. Okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.path.getsize(folder)` to get the size of the folder.
For example:

```
import os
def getFolderSize(folder):
    total_size = os.path.getsize(folder)
    try:
        for item in os.listdir(folder):
            itempath = os.path.join(folder, item)
        
            if os.path.isdir(itempath):
                total_size += getFolderSize(itempath)
            elif os.path.isfile(itempath):
                total_size += os.path.getsize(itempath)
    except Exception:
        print("ex")
    return total_size
a=os.listdir("D:\\")
for folder in a:
    if os.path.isdir("D:\\"+folder):
        print(getFolderSize("D:\\"+folder))
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but this will mention the size of the folder mentioned in the code only right? Actually I want it to display the size of all folders in my drive. Any idea about that?

Comment: Here, ```D:\\``` is the D: drive @heretolearn

Comment: Hey yes thankss! any way to display the name and size both of the folders?

Comment: ```print("Folder name: ",folder," size: ",getFolderSize("D:\\"+folder))```@heretolearn